# How can I handle WebSocket authentication with NextJS and @auth0/nextjs-auth0 library?

Tags: authentication, next.js, websocket, auth0, vercel

I had a long-running HTTP request on an AWS lambda behind an ApiGateway `RestApi`. It kept timing out at the max limit of 29 seconds. I figured I'd move it to a WebSocket to bypass the limit. After some faff, I managed to get that working nicely.

On the front-end, I'm using Auth0 JWTs to authenticate a NestJS app. Authentication happens server-side in a NextJS API function using the `@auth0/nextjs-auth0` library. So the access_token is not available to the front-end client. The JWT is passed to a custom authoriser on the AWS side.

I now want to authenticate the WebSocket with the JWT that is only available server-side.

It'd be daft to handle requests to the WebSocket server-side via an HTTP request. What am I missing?

Do I somehow make another WebSocket handler on the NextJS side and chain the response that way? Do I make calls to the WebSocket from the front-end client and handle auth some other way? I'm honestly a bit lost.

**Update**
I went down the route of making a socket.io api route in Next.JS. I got that working nicely. It seemed like a reasonable idea as the `access_token` is available there. It turns out [Vercel is incompatible](https://vercel.com/guides/do-vercel-serverless-functions-support-websocket-connections) as the serverless functions have restrictive timeouts.

So I guess I need a way to authenticate from the FE. I'd prefer not to resort to having the `access_token` in the FE.

**Update Two**
I've found a lot of useful information about websocket auth here: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/authentication.html. It suggests fetching a short-lived or even single-use token via the authenticated HTTP API is an option.

Comment: It sounds like nestjs-auth0 uses an encrypted session cookie to store the JWT. The websocket API should have access to that same cookie (assuming your websocket and HTTP APIs are hosted on the same site). Maybe you can just have the websocket "piggy back" on the existing auth that you already have working.

Comment: @mamacdon Yeah, that's what I attempted originally, it may work in some cases, but I'm not keen on having another socket handler running anyway. Also, Vercel serverless functions don't seem to support WebSockets anyway: https://vercel.com/guides/do-vercel-serverless-functions-support-websocket-connections. I'm going to implement a short-lived single-use token system.